# PHP error with versions 7.4+ ValueError: Unknown format specifier "C" in

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Why am I getting sprintf(): Too few arguments here php error here while trying to use this in items_wrap on wp_nav_menu()?

```
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object('primary-menu');

$navId = $menu->term_id;
$menuId = 'menu_' . $navId;

$navUrl = get_field('social_media_url', $menuId);
$navImg = get_field('social_media_img', $menuId);

if ($navUrl && $navImg) {
     $socialOption = '<ul id="%s" class="%s">%s<li class="menu-social-option"><a href="' . esc_attr($navUrl) . '" target="_blank"><img src="' . esc_attr($navImg['url'])  . '"></a></li></ul>';
} else {
    $socialOption = '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>';
}

$navArray = array(
                'theme_location' => 'primary', // Defined when registering the menu
                'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
                'container'      => false,
                'depth'          => 2,
                'items_wrap'     => $socialOption,
                'menu_class'     => 'navbar-nav ml-auto',
                'walker'         => new Bootstrap_NavWalker(), // This controls the display of the Bootstrap Navbar
                'fallback_cb'    => 'Bootstrap_NavWalker::fallback', // For menu fallback
            );

wp_nav_menu($navArray);
```

When I remove esc_url($navUrl) then I get this type of error uncaught ValueError: Unknown format specifier "C" in. This only happens with PHP versions 7.4+

Cheers

Comment: What do you want to insert in %1 %2 and %3?

Comment: Perhaps [the `sprintf` documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) might be useful to read?

Comment: %1 would be menu_id, %2 would be menu_class and %3 would be all the menu items. I edited my question with extra infromation

Comment: You have 3 parameters `"%1$s %2$s %3$s` So you need 3 variables to replace those parameters with! _PS_ There is no need for the `1$` etc if you mention the variables in the order that the parameters appear

Comment: I removed sprintf leaving only  $socialOption = '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s<li class="menu-social-option"><a href="' . esc_url($navUrl) . '" target="_blank"><img src="' . esc_url($navImg['url'])  . '"></a></li></ul>';
Now i get Uncaught ValueError: Unknown format specifier "C" in.
But when I remove esc_url($navUrl) it starts working

Comment: Maybe you should show us this code in the context of the code around it. Currently it makes very little sense, please read [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is this supposed to be in a loop

Comment: I edited my question andtried to make it more understandable @RiggsFolly

Comment: I suggest that you play with some simple examples (maybe the ones in the manual) You dont seem to understand how a `sprintf()` works. Your code does no actually put this string `'<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s'` into a sprintf() and you provide no Variables to replace the parameters.

Comment: So now you have removed the `sprintf()` ? What are you going to achieve with that

Comment: What do you want to put in these 3 `%s` in this line `<ul id="%s" class="%s">%s`

Comment: The %3$s  already represents all of the list items. %2$s  already represents  'menu_id' and   %2$s is for menu_class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this issue. Turns out I don't have to use sprintf again.
To wrap an extra item to wp_nav_menu with ACF variables I use this function. If any of ACF variables are empty then it just returns $items which is set by Wordpress.

```
function add_last_nav_item($items)
        {
            $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object('primary-menu');

            $navId = $menu->term_id;
            $menuId = 'menu_' . $navId;

            $navUrl = get_field('social_media_url', $menuId);
            $navImg = get_field('social_media_img', $menuId);
            if ($navUrl && $navImg) {
                return $items .= '<li class="menu-social-option"><a href="' . esc_attr($navUrl) . '" target="_blank"><img src="' . esc_attr($navImg['url'])  . '"></a></li>';
            } else {
                return $items;
            }
        }
        add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_last_nav_item');


        $socialOption = '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>';
```

Thank you @RiggsFolly for helping me figure this out